# Approximate Identities.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let 
       $ K(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    \frac{e^{-1/1-x^2}}{C} & {|x|<1}, \\
      0 &{|x|\geq 1}
      \end{array} \right.$, where $C = \int^{1}_{-1}e^{-1/(1-x^2)}$, and let $K_{t}(x) = \frac{1}{t}K(x/t).$

Prove that the family of operators

$$A_{t}:L^{1}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^{1}(\mathbb{R}),  A_{t}(f) = f*K_{t},$$

is uniformly bounded.

Could anyone how can I solve this, if the only given information that I have is the following theorem:

[image]

Or this theorem is not needed for solving this excercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than that. There is a named result called Young's inequality that tells you that if $1 \leq p,q,r \leq \infty$ satisfy $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{r} + 1$ and $f \in L^p$, then the operator $g \mapsto f*g$ is bounded as an operator from $L^q$ to $L^r$. It also gives you a bound on the operator norm, which as you might expect is $\| f \|_{L^p}$. Since this does your problem in its entirety, you should probably figure out how to prove this yourself rather than just citing it.

Comment: could you tell me a book contains this inequality.

Comment: @weakmathematician It should be somewhere in almost any measure-theory level book on real analysis.